# Error unattended-upgrades 0.93

Tags: xubuntu, 17.04

Every time my computer boots up, an error shows.

[unattended-upgrades 0.93.1 ubuntu2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSp3F.png)

Edit

[Traceback information-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN0Av.png)
[Traceback information-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpLZD.png)

Comment: The complete traceback would be more useful. You have provided only the package name. Um, 17.04 will be EOL soon.

Comment: @user535733 | how to view traceback?

Comment: Look again at the error window. It's there. It's on the image you posted.

Comment: @user535733 | can I uninstall this package?